# How do I nullify (or assign another value to) a System.ConsoleKey value once it's finished being used?

Tags: c#, .net, input, console, console-application

I have a repeating code here, full of `goto` statements that make this while loop well... Repeat forever.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            main();
        }

        public static ConsoleKeyInfo keyPressed;

        private static void main()
        {
            start:
            keyPressed = Console.ReadKey();

            while (true)
            {
                loopstart:

                if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You pressed the Enter Key!");
                    goto loopstart;
                }
                if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You pressed the Escape Key!");
                    goto loopstart;
                }
                if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You pressed the Spacebar!");
                    goto loopstart;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("You broke the loop!");
            goto start;
        }
    }
}
```

Without removing any code, is it possible to change the value of `keyPressed.Key` or `keyPressed` itself to `NULL`; the state it was when it was declared, or to any other value/key that's not the spacebar, enter or escape key?

Of course, the problem could be solved by removing all the `goto loopstart;` in the code, but that's against the point of the question.

What I want to do is make the `keyPressed.Key` value `NULL` (or any other value) so that all the `IF` statements will result in false, which therefore means not running the `goto loopstart` code.

---

The problem now is that when I try to nullify it with a simple `keyPressed = null;`, it comes with the error of:

> Cannot convert null to 'System.ConsoleKeyInfo' because it is a non-nullable value type.

**Is there any way I can nullify (or change the value to something else) so that I can break the loop?**
(As in: Make the `IF` statement get to the point where it has to run the `else` code)

It should look something like:

```
...

{
    loopstart:
    if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You pressed the Enter Key!");
        // keyPressed = null; <-- Does not work.
        // Do something to make ConsoleKey.Key to equal something else.
        goto loopstart;
    }
    if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You pressed the Escape Key!");

...
```

Obviously with the `// Do something to make ConsoleKey.Key to equal something else.` replaced with working code?

If this works, the first time the loop runs (presuming the key pressed at the start is either the Spacebar, Escape or Enter keys) would result with the `goto loopstart;` being used, and the second time round would skip through to the `goto start;` where it'll ask for another key.
*And then the process repeats at the speed of which the user gives an input, rather than repeating with the same key without stop, or asking for another key.*

Basically: Make the loop run the `IF` statement as a proper `IF` statement instead of a `FOR` loop.

[See also](https://github.com/Ahsome/Guards-of-Aetheria/commit/d7c6bc8b93574be36415ec0ef9b50d915283e2a6)

Comment: unless your leaving out logic at the end of the while loop theres no point in the goto statements. is there a reason you don't just allow the loop to... well to loop? and why not just put the keyPressed = Console.ReadKey at the beginning of the loop, then no need for 'goto: start'.

Comment: The thing with my problem is that the `Console.ReadKey();` is done in a class, while the loop is in another. So, there's obviously no way to break a loop without going back to the first class.

Comment: in this case you should look into Events. You can call an event whenever you get a keypressed, you will have subscribed to listen for the event in the other class and have the logic you need in the event handler.

Comment: (Continued) See [this](https://github.com/Ahsome/Guards-of-Aetheria/tree/New-UI-Handling/GuardsOfAetheria) for more information. | UI.cs Line 42 and CharacterCreation.cs Line 167

Comment: also, another way to do this would be to handle the key press in the windows messaging pump instead of in your code. Obviously there are multiple solutions, without knowing the full scope of the project I can't say which is best, but for ignoring user input I usually override the native windows WndProc method or override a C# control's KeyPressed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why use `goto`-statement, it's very outdated constructure. You can easily `continue` the loop. And `else` check is also redundant. You can simply read the key from `Console` before check, like this:

```
while (true)
{
    keyPressed = Console.ReadKey();

    switch (keyPressed.Key)
    {
        case ConsoleKey.Enter:
            Console.WriteLine("You pressed the Enter Key!");
            continue;

        case ConsoleKey.Escape:
            Console.WriteLine("You pressed the Escape Key!");
            continue;

        case ConsoleKey.Spacebar:
            Console.WriteLine("You pressed the Spacebar!");
            continue;
    }
    // should be outside the switch for breaking the loop
    break;
}
```

If you want to clear `keyPressed`, use `default` construction, like this:

```
keyPressed = default(ConsoleKeyInfo);
```

But why do you want to do this? Garbage Collection will clear the memory by itself, you should not go into there.

Comment: The reason for such (the necessarity to clear the value) is that so that the current method doesn't continue on and on and on... Almost as if it was a `for` statement instead of a `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            main();
        }

        public static ConsoleKeyInfo keyPressed;

        private static void main()
        {
        start:
            keyPressed = Console.ReadKey();

            while (true)
            {
            loopstart:

                if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You pressed the Enter Key!");
                    keyPressed = new ConsoleKeyInfo('a', ConsoleKey.A, false, false, false);
                    goto loopstart;
                }
                if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You pressed the Escape Key!");
                    goto loopstart;
                }
                if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You pressed the Spacebar!");
                    goto loopstart;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("You broke the loop!");
            goto start;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answer, but it works. Will wait for an answer regarding nulling the value to its original state (so that in the event of all keyboard keys are used...) before accepting.

Comment: Consider improving your answer. _[Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)_